# How to read and parse JSON in shell scripting without using json tool and JQ tool

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to download artifacts(.war file) from artifactory through rest api. I am getting folder names from artifactory in JSON format and I wanted to get that in one variable through shell script but I am not able to do that without using JSON tool and JQ tool as my server does not contain both of these. Can someone please help me with these.

I tried below commands

```
$ databasename=`cat process.json | json select '.uri'`
$ echo $databasename
```

and

```
$ databasename=`jq '.uri' process.json`
```

as I do not have JQ and JSON tool, it failed.

```
$ curl -u User:API Key https://artifactory.es.abc.com/artifactory/api/storage/abc/com/xyz/aa/bb/xx/?list&listFolders=1&includeRootPath=0  > process.json
$ databasename=`cat process.json | json select '.uri'`
$ echo $databasename
```

Comment: See the answers using `python` in the linked duplicate. (There are also some `awk`-based solutions, but they're less capable for the usual reasons).

Comment: ...and note that *none* of your answers parse JSON in the formal meaning of the word "parse", or the broad meaning of "JSON" as "all documents that comply with the JSON specification". There are lots of corner cases a textual parser will know nothing about -- if something contains `\"` instead of a literal quote, for example, that needs to turn into a `"` in the data instead of ending the string it's part of. And string *can* contain quotes (if thusly quoted), or curly braces... etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of `grep` and `sed` to obtain the data you need. I would have added a full example, but the URL is not correct and you haven't supplied (a part of) the json.

```
$ cat tmp.json
{
        "json": {
                 "array": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
        },
        "uri": "derp"
}
$ grep 'uri' tmp.json | sed -r 's/^[^:]*:(.*)$/\1/'
 "derp"
```

For data on a single line, you can make use of the following command:

```
echo '{ "uri" : "/abc", "folder" : true },' | grep -Eo '"uri"[^,]*' | grep -Eo '[^:]*$'
```

The first grep will search for "uri" and everything after until a comma is found, the second grep extracts everything from the colon to the end of the string.

Comment: I tried with your solution but getting below error-
line 2: {: command not found
line 3: uri: command not found
2nd line is-
curl -u User:API Key https://artifactory.es.abc.com/artifactory/api/storage/abc/com/xyz/aa/bb/xx/?list&listFolders=1&includeRootPath=0  > tmp.json
3rd Line is -
grep 'uri' tmp.json | sed -r 's/^[^:]*:(.*)$/\1/'

My data is like-
{ "uri" : "/abc", "folder" : true },

Comment: echo '{ "uri" : "/abc", "folder" : true },' | grep -Eo '"uri"[^,]*' | grep -Eo '[^:]*$' 
worked for me.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

The more readable and easy to understand solution would be:

```
cat process.json | tr { '\n' | tr , '\n' | tr } '\n' | grep "uri" | awk  -F'"' '{print $4}'
```

Comment: `awk` can do all the work of `tr` *and* `grep` *and* `sed`, and `cat` is never needed when reading only a single file (its job is to *concatenate* multiple files into a single stream). `cat foo | bar` gives `bar` only a FIFO, whereas `bar <foo` gives it a real file handle for its stdin; that's an especially big deal when `bar` is something that can benefit from being able to `seek()` around in its input (f/e, to parallelize I/O operations between different threads, as `sort` does) or to interrogate the FD to get its length in constant-time instead of needing to read front-to-back.

Comment: `awk -F'"' '/uri/{print $(NF-1)}' process.json`